# NOT EXISTS with multiple criteria and indirect unique id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

I am having a hard time understanding this query with `NOT EXISTS` in SQL Server.

My colleague helped me with this query which works fine. There are 3 tables basically and I want to see if `work_q_id` exists in `t_allocation` table or not but `t_allocation` does not have a column (key) which matches the `work_q_id` that's why I had to join it with pick table. In short, it works like this:

```
work -> pick -> allocation
```

My question is how does `NOT EXISTS` know which `work_q_id` does not exist in `t_allocation` when `t_allocation` does not even have that column?

`Pick` table has `work_q_id` which was used to join with work table and `t_allocation` also has `pick_id` which I used to join with pick table to be able to identify the `work_q_ids` that do not exist.

Can someone please help me understand the concept?

Thanks in advance

```
select 
    wkq.wh_id, wkq.work_q_id
from 
    work wkq with (NOLOCK)
inner join 
    pick pkd WITH (NOLOCK) on pkd.work_q_id = wkq.work_q_id
                           and pkd.wh_id = wkq.wh_id
where 
    wkq.work_type in ('72')
    and wkq.work_status = 'U'
    and (wkq.pick_ref_number like ('%PICK_PRIME%')
         or wkq.description like 'TopOff%')
    and pkd.status = 'RELEASED'
    --and (CONVERT(VARCHAR , CONVERT(DATETIME , wkq.datetime_stamp AT TIME ZONE ('UTC') AT TIME ZONE ('Eastern Standard Time')) , 120)) <= '2021-05-26 15:33:00' 
    and (CONVERT(VARCHAR , CONVERT(DATETIME , wkq.datetime_stamp AT TIME ZONE ('UTC') AT TIME ZONE ('Eastern Standard Time')) , 120)) <= DATEADD(hh, -24, (CONVERT(VARCHAR , CONVERT(DATETIME , GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE ('UTC') AT TIME ZONE ('Eastern Standard Time')) , 120)))
    and not exists (select 1 from t_allocation alc WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE pkd.wh_id = alc.wh_id 
                AND pkd.pick_id = alc.pick_id
                AND pkd.work_q_id = wkq.work_q_id)
```

Comment: Do you *really* need all of those `NOLOCK` hints? You *do* understand the consequences of using said hint, I assume?

Comment: Side note: Why would you convert datetimes to varchar for the purposes of comparison (less than or equal to)? Why not compare them in their native type?

Comment: @Larnu - Because we have big data and it does kind of optimizes the performance. I understand that it has disadvantage as well i.e. uncommitted data. Please let me know if there is anything else which I should be considering as I am still pretty beginner

Comment: @lgor - Thanks for your input. I will do more research and see how to to use it that way. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Have a read of [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for the article. I did not realize that it's could affect especially the reporting that much. Thanks again for this

Comment: You may want to investigate `SNAPSHOT` isolation, which can help with big, blocking report queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your query, the `EXISTS` is a *correlated* subquery: in other words, it has one or more outer references to the rest of the query.**

Looking just at the relevant parts:

```sql
from 
    work wkq
inner join 
    pick pkd......
```

So `wkq` and `pkd` are the *outer* table references

---

```sql
where 
....
    not exists (select 1
```

What you actually select in an `EXISTS` query is irrelevant, so `1` is fine, `NOT` inverts the `EXISTS` obviously

---

```sql
 from t_allocation alc WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Now `alc` is the *inner* reference

---

```sql
                    WHERE pkd.wh_id = alc.wh_id 
                AND pkd.pick_id = alc.pick_id
```

These two lines are correlations between the inside reference and the outside reference, so the `EXISTS` will only pick out rows that match these conditions

---

```sql
                AND pkd.work_q_id = wkq.work_q_id)
```

This is interesting. It is not a correlation, because there are no inner references, only outer.

It is a startup filter: the `EXISTS` will only return rows if this *outer-reference* condition is true

Comment: Awesome. Thanks explains a lot. I was basically confused about and pkd.work_q_id = wkq.work_q_id because it is indirect reference which is what I wanted. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
            wkq.wh_id
        ,   wkq.work_q_id
from        work            wkq
inner join  pick            pkd     on  pkd.work_q_id   =   wkq.work_q_id
                                    and pkd.wh_id       =   wkq.wh_id
left join   t_allocation    alc     on  alc.pick_id     =   pkd.pick_id
                                    
where       alc.pick_id IS NULL
        and wkq.work_type   in  ('72')
        and wkq.work_status =   'U'
        and (
                    wkq.pick_ref_number like    '%PICK_PRIME%'
                or  wkq.description     like    'TopOff%'
            )
        and pkd.status      =   'RELEASED'
        and (
                                    CONVERT(VARCHAR , CONVERT(DATETIME , wkq.datetime_stamp AT TIME ZONE ('UTC') AT TIME ZONE ('Eastern Standard Time')) , 120)) <= 
                DATEADD(hh, -24, (  CONVERT(VARCHAR , CONVERT(DATETIME , GETDATE()          AT TIME ZONE ('UTC') AT TIME ZONE ('Eastern Standard Time')) , 120))
            )
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy. This worked perfectly but I just wanted to understand the concept of NOT EXISTS and how it is working. Can you please help me understand that as well?

Comment: If you want to know if certain "pick_id" from Table "pick" does not exist in Table "t_allocation",
then it would be something like this:

SELECT *
FROM pick
WHERE pick_id NOT EXISTS IN
    (
     select pick_id 
     from t_allocation alc
    )

In your example:
1. The field to look for in the NOT EXISTS is missing (pick_id)
2. The select is always returning 1 in "select 1". So, it is always returning 1.